# Problems in understanding a code that counts, and returns the prime numbers up to, and including an input number

Tags: python

I have 3 questions. 1) Why can't I use `if,else` statements here, after the `for` loop in the code (Doesn't return any value in the code i wrote), 2) In case of using `for,else` why do we need to add a `break` statement after the `if` statement, and lastly, what will it do ? I am new to python and thanks in advance!

```
def count_primes(num):    
    primes = [2]    
    x = 3

    if num < 2:    
        return 0

    while x <= num:    
        for y in range(3,x,2):    
            if x%y==0:    
                x+=2    
            else:    
                primes.append(x)    
                x+=2    
    print(primes)    
    return len(primes)
```

Comment: Hi Omar, for your first question, the list generated by the range built-in function in your code do not create any value(  try to print this command print(list(range(3,3,2)))  ), and this produce that for any number num greater than 2, your code will be forever in the while loop

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you increment x by 2 *while* you are still inside your for loop! That means `for y in range(3,x,2):` will never break because you keep increasing x while you are inside the loop. Instead, you should put `x += 2` outside of the loop. The `break` statement terminates the current iteration of the loop, so you should use `break` inside the condition `if x%y==0:` since this means x is divisible by y and therefore not prime (so we can move on to testing the next value of x).

Also you need to make sure you aren't adding duplicates to your primes list so you should change your conditional to test that `x` isn't already in your `primes` list.

```
def count_primes(num):    
    primes = [2,3]    
    x = 3

    if num < 2:    
        return 0

    while x <= num:   
        for y in range(3,x,2):   
            # print("testing", x, "%", y)
            if x%y==0:    
                break  
            else:
                if x not in primes:    
                    primes.append(x)
                else:
                    continue 
        x += 2 
    print(primes)    
    return len(primes)
```

Output:

```
>>> count_primes(11)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
5
>>> count_primes(23)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
9
```

Comment: wrong output, because `3` is a prime number, and it's missing from the sample output

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Fixed by initializing primes to [2, 3]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop over and over all numbers, since you already have all your primes:

```
def count_primes(num):    
    primes = [2]    

    if num < 2:    
        return 0

    for x in range(3,num+1,2) :
        if all( x%p != 0 for p in primes ) :
            primes.append(x)

    print(primes)    
    return len(primes)
```

Testing:

```
>>> count_primes(13)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
6
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In algorithms world, when we want to prove the existence of something, it is enough to get an example. But when we want to prove something is not exist, we have to search the whole space of the problem and then we can say it does not exist.
   in this problem, because we want to say that ***num*** is not divisible by any number, so the divisibility test should be performed on all the numbers. So we have to use the for loop
2. If ***num*** was divisible by one, it is not a prime number. So we don't need to look at bigger numbers and we can break